# Sim command with setpoint step

Tags: matlab

I am plotting my manipulated variables and plant output in Matlab using the `sim` command:

```
sim(MPC, 500/T_p, [h_0, T_0]);
```

`MPC` being of course the simulated model, and `[h_0, T_0]` are the setpoints of the plant's output. It works fine, but the setpoints are constant in time. Is there any way I can configure the `sim` command to make the setpoints change in time (for example step + 50% after n intervals)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether `sim` can take an `[nx2]` matrix as input, otherwise you could loop over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Adriaan is right, `sim` can indeed take matrix of `[n x 2]` dimension as input. So, the answer is roughly:

```
% step properties
step_time = 50;
h_step_coeff = 1.5;
T_step_coeff = 1;

% construct setpoints matrix, run simulation
offset = round(step_time/T_p);
setpoints = repmat([h_0, T_0], offset, 1);
setpoints_step =  repmat([h_0*h_step_coeff, T_0*T_step_coeff], round(500/T_p) - offset, 1);
setpoints = cat(1, setpoints, setpoints_step);
sim(MPC, 500/T_p, setpoints);
```